# Максимально быстрый алгоритм сравнения 2х строк

Tags: windows, delphi, алгоритм

Имеется программа для сравнения 2х баз вида:

```
123
234
456
```

При совпадении значений строка удаляется в новой базе.
Базы большие(по 300т строк) и скорость получается очень маленькой.
Вот кусок моего кода:

```
 while i <= ListNBD.Count-1 do
 begin
  StrN:=ListNBD[i];                  //строка и3 новой базы
  j:=0;
  while j <= ListBD.Count-1 do       //идем по строкам старой базы
    begin
    StrB:=ListBD[j];                 //строка и3 старой базы
  if (Length(StrN)=Length(StrB))then //если строки равны по кол-ву символов
   if (StrN=StrB) then               //сравнение   {САМА ПРОВЕРКА}
      begin
        ListNBD.Delete(i);           //удаляем из новой базы
        Inc(DelStatusB);             //увеличиваем статус удаленных строк
        i:=i-1;                      //перемещаемся назад на 1 запись
        break;                       //выходим из 1 цикла
      end;
    Inc(j);
    end;
  inc(i);
  Inc(StatusB);
 end;
```

Подскажите хороший алгоритм для более быстрого сравнения строк.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!
По хешам смотрел в интернете, ничего нормального и понятного не нашел.
Есть ли у кого пример данного алгоритма по хешам?
//
Либо я чего-то не понял, либо мои комментарии кто-то удаляет...

Comment: @PIN, [вот тут](http://digipen2.xmmg.com/dpweb/Courses/CS280/HashFunctions-1.html) много функций для вычисления хэш-кода строки. 

Остаток от деления кода на размер таблицы дает индекс элемента в таблице. В этом элементе держите указатель на список строк с одинаковым хэш-кодом. Такой метод называется разрешение коллизий списками. 

Если размер таблицы раза в полтора больше всего количества строк, то искать будет очень быстро, практически за одно обращение.

Надеюсь теперь понятно ?

Comment: Спасибо. А примера на delphi/pascal нету?
А то с С++ не очень пока дружу.

Comment: @PIN, откровенно говоря, я с delphi вообще не знаком.

По Вашему комментарию (о 5-10 строк/сек) у меня сложилось впечатление, что объекты ListNBD и ListBD как-то непосредственно отображены в файл (или файлы, возможно с кэшированием) на диске и каждая операция их обновления приводит к работе с диском. 

Это правильная догадка ?

Если да, то причина медленной работы именно в этом.

Comment: Объекты ListNBD и ListBD это TStringList.В них загружены данные из Memo.
Они не обновляются и работы с диском нет.Только при первоначальной загрузки самих баз.
-Идет загрузка в ListNBD и ListBD.
-Обрабатывается и удаляются повторы.
-и выводится.
Код который выложен мной полностью почти из потока.

Comment: Тогда с загрузкой в хэш-таблицу в памяти старой базы (ListBD как я понимаю) и *построением, а не удалением строк из нее* новой все будет очень быстро (секунды).

Смотрите:

1. Читаете и хэшируете все строки ListBD

2. Читаете по одной строки новой базы (ListNBD) и поверяете (примерно одно обращение) есть ли она в ListBD.

3. Если нет, пишете эту строку в новый вариант новой базы (скажем, ListNNBD) на диск.

4. То, что получилось в ListNNBD переименовываете в ListNBD.

--

Если правильно понял задачу, то все.

Comment: @PIN смотрите мой ответ, думаю такой результат вполне приемлем.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Отсортировать базы и сравнивать за один проход.
2. Залить в какую-нить БД, добавить индексов, фильтровать там.

сложно что-то более конкретное советовать...

**UPD** Использование THashedStringList.
Входные данные: два файла в одном 300к строк ([base1.txt](http://base1.txt)), в другом 600к строк ([base2.txt](http://base2.txt)). Во втором файле каждая вторая строка из первого файла. Длина строк 100 символов (влияет на скорость вычисления хэша). Хэш строится за ~секунду по 300к строкам.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SL_Old: THashedStringList;
  SL_New: TStringList;
  SL_Result: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Start:'+DateTimeToStr(Now));
  SL_Old:=THashedStringList.Create;
  SL_New:=TStringList.Create;
  SL_Result:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL_Old.LoadFromFile('c:\base1.txt');
    SL_New.LoadFromFile('c:\base2.txt');
    for i:=0 to SL_New.Count-1 do
    begin
      if SL_Old.IndexOf(SL_New[i])<0 then
        SL_Result.Add(SL_New[i]);
    end;
    SL_Result.SaveToFile('c:\baseresult.txt');
  finally
    SL_Old.Free;
    SL_New.Free;
    SL_Result.Free;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Finish:'+DateTimeToStr(Now));
  end;
end;
```

Время работы 1,5 минуты.
Если поменять местами файлы, т.е. хэшировать бОльший файл, то время работы - 1 минута.
Если использовать TStringList, то поиск строк будет аналогичен коду в вопросе, там все плохо естественно, через 10 минут прервал выполнение.

Для интересующихся в THashedStringList хэш-функция используется такая:

```
function TStringHash.HashOf(const Key: string): Cardinal;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 1 to Length(Key) do
    Result := ((Result shl 2) or (Result shr (SizeOf(Result) * 8 - 2))) xor
      Ord(Key[I]);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Разбирался сейчас еще раз с сортировкой.
Сортировка без потока была достаточно долгой, а вот в потоке все достаточно быстро.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а как Вы объясните, что 

    "Если поменять местами файлы, т.е. хэшировать бОльший файл, то время работы - 1 минута"

т.е. быстрее (на 0.5 мин.) ?

Неужели использование SL_Result.Add() столь неэффективно ? 

Что будет, если сразу писать строки в файл (естественно с буферизацией и без "sync") ?

IMHO сама запись в файл ~30Мбайт не может занимать больше нескольких секунд (правда мой опыт осован в основном на Си).

Comment: @avp Ну у меня был синтетический тест. просто поменял местами, выходной файл стал пустым, может добавление в список играет роль. Не старался добиться одинакового результата, порядок работы остался прежним...

Comment: Код работает прекрасно и скорость хорошая.
Спасибо большое за пример!
Я даже не ожидал что все будет так просто:)

Comment: Нашел как исправить чтоб поиск зависел от регистра: StringList.CaseSensitive:= True;

Answer (score 9):

*(Сходу в голову приходят два варианта, если реализовывать ваш алгоритм самостоятельно)*

- Составить из обеих последовательностей два сортированных списка и применить к ним [алгоритм слияния](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), который будет отбрасывать повторяющиеся элементы.

> Алгоритмическая сложность - **`O(N log N)`**, где `N = max(N1, N2)`, поскольку сортировка займет время, равное `O(N log N)`, а алгоритм слияния - `O(N)`.

- Добавить все элементы в хэш-таблицу, а в случае возникновения коллизий, сравнивать элементы и удалять, если они *действительно совпадают*. Далее - просто перечислить все элементы, добавленные в хэш-таблицу.

> - Строго проанализировать алгоритмическую сложность *(как и всегда в случае хэширования)* в этом случае довольно-таки непросто - для полноценного обоснования рекомендую обратиться к [**`[Cormen]` Introduction to algorithms.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm)
> - Но, если прикинуть сложность алгоритма, то она будет стремиться к **`O(N)`**, поскольку затраты на вставку элементов в хэш-таблицу должны составлять `O(N(1 + A))`, где `A` - медленно растущая функция, а перечисление всех элементов в хэш-таблице однозначно можно реализовать за `O(N)`.
> - В этом обосновании не учитываются временные затраты на удаление совпадающих элементов, а также делается предположение о том, что хэширование идеально и равномерно. Но, предполагаю, что на практике результат получится достаточно близким к теоретическому.

Comment: Первый вариант еще можно назвать "интересным", т.к тут присутствует хоть какая-то логика. А вот второй вариант - это уже простецкая банальщина, ведь получается, что по-любому придется сравнивать новое значение со всеми значениями, которые были в базе. Здесь лишь запутывает выражение:
  
      Добавить все элементы в хэш-таблицу

А алгоритм будет точно такой же( и по времени ), как и обычное последовательное сравнение каждой запись в БД с новым значением.

Comment: @Dexter, в случае хеш-таблицы по каждой строке будет проведен только один проход, а не от 1 до N как в случае обычного сравнения каждого со всеми. А уже сравнение числовых значений хешей явно будет быстрее сравнения строк.

Comment: @Dexter Судя по всему, вы не очень-то представляете себе, как устроена хэш-таблица. Одинаковые элементы имеют одинаковые хэши => в хэш-таблице они попадут в один и тот же `bucket`. Ни с какими другими элементами они не сравниваются в принципе, только с теми, которые расположены в одном и том же `bucket'e`/.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.
Хочу попробовать это все с хешем, но в интернете по этому вопросу маловато информации.
Не мог ли кто дать маленький пример по хешам.

Comment: А что делать, если у двух разных строк одинаковые хэши?

Comment: @ReinRaus, это и называется коллизиями) - уязвимостью ХЭШ-функций...

Comment: @Asen, коллизии - обычное дело для хеш функций (можно даже сказать, неизбежность). Если задача не связана с криптографией, то коллизия - не уязвимость, а обычный рабочий момент.

Comment: @asen уязвимость **всех** хэш-функций, Вы наверно хотели сказать? :)  
Я конечно понимаю, что шанс совпадения хэша весьма мал, но он есть. Хотя если пропажа строк не критична, то можно об этом и не задумываться.

Comment: Мда, а я-то не верил, когда мне говорили, что `xakep.ru` наносит `irreversible brain damage`.

Comment: @ReinRaus, чтобы строки не терялись, хеш-таблицу нужно организовать в виде массива списков например (эти списки и называются bucket'ами). Чтобы добавить элемент в таблицу, применяем к нему хеш-функцию, находим список с соответствующим номером и добавляем в него данный элемент. Чтобы найти какой-то элемент, опять же применяем к нему хеш-функцию, находим нужный список, ищем в нем данный элемент. В идеальном случае в каждом списке должно быть не больше одного элемента. Если их там больше - ничего страшного, все равно, к примеру, десять сравнений это лучше чем миллион)

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.
Смотрел в интернете про хеш но там ничего почти нету.
Немног бы кто написать пример по сравнению по этим хешам

Comment: @PIN ищите примеры в сети по THashedStringList, TBucketList... В любом случае мгновенную скорость вам не даст ни один из вариантов.
Если писать свой вариант хэшмапа, то надо проводить исследования по вашим данным в каких случаях какая хэш-функция даст оптимальный результат, это непросто.

Comment: Подтверждаю, применение хэш-таблицы - здесь оптимальный вариант. 

У меня в практике был случай - необходимо было очень быстро проверять, имеется ли в базе ссылок новый URL и добавлять, если нет. В базе несколько миллионов ссылок.

Взял хэш [FNV (Fowler-Noll-Vo)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNV). Модифицировал на 24 битные хэши => массив на 16 с хвостиком миллионов элементов по 4 байта (старший просто не использовался). 

FNV используется, например, в DNS, memcache и в некоторых реализациях hash_map для C++.

[Подробнее на английском](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).

Comment: @northerner, спасибо !

Ознакомился с FNV, отличная функция.

Answer (score 2):

Еще как вариант: построить [бор](http://cs.mipt.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) из первого списка и поиск слова из второго будет равен его длине

Могут правда возникнуть проблемы с памятью, если в первой базе слишком много слов

Comment: В первой базе очень много слов.
Но за вариант спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В помощь вам операторы SQL:

`EXCEPT
INTERSECT
UNION
UNION ALL`

Построчная обработка таблиц - это жесть!

Comment: ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ

Comment: @ЫЫЫ, а кто сказал, что ТС работает с СУБД? В задании только пара списков со строками.

А вообще на огромных массивах данных (даже в СУБД), "ручками" можно сделать более эффективный алгоритм чем средствами SQL.

Comment: в данном контексте можно сделать и словарями, я не спорю. 
Но построчная обработка таблиц СУБД все таки жесть.
Ручками вам все равно надо будет данные таблицы селектировать, так что прийдется учитывать скорость вытягивания данных.
Разве мой пост не полезен?

Comment: Я раньше тоже думал, что жесть. Но кто-то на Хэшкоде убедил меня попробовать. Простая агрегация суммы по группам уже на 100К записей выходила быстрее чем средствами СУБД. И без всякой жести. Все довольно компактно.

Comment: Ну да ну да, если считать что это один разок запустить, нету многопользовательского доступа, плюс каждый раз файл сканировать. Я тоже пересчитывал выгрузки на с++ миллионы записей. Но это страшный велосипед и очень ограниченный. Не спорю быстрее. Кто не любит SQL смотрит в сторону noSQL)