# Сравнить две таблицы и дополнить одну таблицу не достающими данными

Tags: delphi, sql, mysql

Нужно сравнить две таблицы из разных баз данных Одна таблицы в My SQL 2012 друга в Fairbird. Эти таблицы имеют одинаковые поля но разные названия таблицы. Как это можно осуществить? Просто перенос данных с одной одной таблицы в другую получается, но как только в в таблице My SQL 2012 появляется новая запись не знаю как добавить ее в таблицу Fairbird.
Подскажите как это осуществить?

Comment: Fairbird ? название прикольное, но такой субд кажется нет, как нет и браузера Fairfox :)

Comment: Прошу прощение FIREBIRD

Answer (score 1):

1. делаете select id from table1 из главной базы
2. загоняете эти idшники в хэш-таблицу
3. делаете select id from table2 из второй базы
4. бежите по выборке, ищите idшники в хэш-таблице
5. как только запись с id не обнаружилась переливаете ее.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125419/delphi-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-2%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) человек примерно тоже самое делал, только там строки были и файлы, а не базы...

Comment: Спасибо Yura Ivanov за Вашу помощь.
  Что то не получается. Там работают с ХЕШОМ, а у меня таблицы в разных базах, к которым я присоединяюсь. 
   Подскажите/дайте небольшой пример как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: @kadekin778, я написал примерный общий алгоритм. реализовать его предлагаю вам. по ссылке задача решена с точностью до "файл vs база".  
Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Триггером на INSERT отслеживать вставку в одну таблицу и повторять соответствующее действие в другую. Из второй можно также и в первую. Можно аналогично сделать с UPDATE и DELETE.

http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Спасибо. Я почитал. Но там не указано как описать такой триггер, который должен отслеживать какие записи уже есть в таблице, а какие нужно добавить. 
  Если не затруднит описать небольшой пример.

Comment: Так как основная база расположена в оболочке MySQL 2012 и к ней обращается программа не моя. Соответсвенно в этой базе (таблице) я не могу дописать тригер. 
  Моя программа обращается к базе (таблице) в оболочке FIREBIRD. И мне нужно в эту таблицу переносить - дописывать значения внесенные/добавленные из таблицы  MySQL 2012.
  Подскажите как это осуществить, что бы не было дублирующих записей.

Comment: @kadekin778
В триггере становится доступна специальная readonly-таблица inserted, в которой лежат вставляемые данные. И, пардон, я сначала кинулся в вас ссылкой по MSSQL Server по невнимательности. По-моему, нечто подобное доступно и в MySQL, остается загуглить.

Comment: @kadekin778
В вашем случае, думаю, так или иначе, через триггер на вставку в Firebird придется проверять наличие вставляемой записи в MySQL, во избежание дублирования. Суть такая: внутри триггера (в доступной вам СУБД) берем вставляемые данные, организуем запрос по ним в другую таблицу. Если там affected rows > 0, то ничего не делаем и выходим из триггера (вставка только в таблицу самого Firebird), если иначе - делаем еще и INSERT во вторую таблицу с теми же данными.